# unwanted wordpress login page redirect

Tags: redirect, wp-admin

I think I'm hacked. When I want to login to dashboard, the login page redirects.

I discovered it's because of `wp-includes` directory and I replaced the directory with a clean version and so it didn't redirect. But after some hours or some days it redirects again!

Itried disabling the plugins and changing the active theme but nothing changed.

Iinserted some codes in `.htaccess` (p`ublic_html`) file but the problem still exist!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F,L]
RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F,L]
</IfModule>

<Files ~ “^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])”>
order allow,deny
deny from all
satisfy all
</files>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: of course it's about web developing. it's about wordpress codes, database, directories. maybe some codes are needed for stop executing js files or php files or another solutions that are related to web develop. i have seen many similar questions in stackoverflow and you let theme published. thanks